# EC2 public DNS showing 404 without https

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, cpanel, whm

I am new to AWS EC2, i had just setup an ec2 with whm cpanel, my public dns ip is not working without https, its showing 404 not found, but with https its working fine with a non secure red badge in the url. I would like to use ec2 public dns without HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a problem with the security groups associated with your EC2 instances.
While you may have setting to allow traffic on port 443 which is https, port 80 might be missing from your whitelisted ports

To allow traffic on port 80 and 443, you must configure the associated security group and network access control list (network ACL).

For more details check [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/)